# Protecting a document that you sell

Tags: drm

I have written a short guidebook that I have been selling hardcopy. There is now interest in a digital version. How do I protect this guidebook so only the people who purchase it have access to it? I don't want them to be able to forward it to someone or load onto more than one computer?

Comment: I would just use a digitial publishing platform (iBook, Amazon Kindle, etc) and let them handle that for you. They all support some form of DRM or another.

Comment: In your case, I would recommend self-publishing an Ebook using a third party like Amazon as this seems like the *best* solution in your situation. **However,** to answer your question -or rather to prompt others to in depth, [the concept of DRM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_rights_management) is what you are looking for. It seems you want to know how to potentially roll out your own DRM (perhaps so you can keep 100% of sales). I would hope that someone could explain a good way for you to [rollout your own DRM](http://www.drumlinsecurity.com/).

Comment: Without this turning into an anti-DRM argument, the only real way of preventing piracy is to make buying the document or book more appealing than pirating it in my opinion. If you do decide to go with rolling your own DRM, keep in mind that you're probably going to end up doing 80% of the work preventing 20% of your readers from pirating.

Answer (score 8):

In general, this is impossible.  Anything your users can access, they can create an insecure copy of.

That said, this is a problem that people have tried to solve before, and they have come up with some partially effective methods (see iBook or Amazon Kindle, as vcsjones suggested in a comment).  These methods rely in part on punishing violators, so that copying the document, while nowhere near impossible, is difficult and unappealing.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?